# I've created a custom footer in Excel. Now how do I remove it, permanently?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I've created a custom footer; Page Layout -> Print Titles -> Header/Footer -> Custom Footer...

Once I've created it, I can't find the option to remove it (permanently). When making copies of the workbook, the 'custom footer' lingers...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Does this work (from [here](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Remove-a-header-or-footer-from-a-worksheet-370a2243-3685-40a9-a8a6-85da140be7b0))

> On the Page Layout tab, in the Page Setup group, click the arrow.
>
> Click the arrow to open the Page Setup box
>
> In the Page Setup box, on the Header/Footer tab, do one of the
>   following:
>
> Under Footer, select (none).
>
> Click anywhere in the worksheet, and then click View > Normal.